# Is there a way to use PhantomJS's onResourceRequested callback in the Java driver?

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, phantomjs

I want to avoid loading css files in PhantomJS.  I'm using the Java driver.
I saw a nice example js code for PhantomJS like this:

```
page.onResourceRequested = function(requestData, request) {
    if ((/http:\/\/.+?\.css/gi).test(requestData['url']) || requestData['Content-Type'] == 'text/css') {
        request.abort();
    }
};
```

My code is using the PhantomJSDriver like this (scala):

```
val sb = new PhantomJSDriverService.Builder()
val svc = sb.usingPhantomJSExecutable(new java.io.File("./phantomjs")).usingCommandLineArguments(Array("--load-images=false","--disk-cache=true")).build()
```

Is there a way I can achieve the same thing, perhaps via the Java API?

Answer (score 12):

I was able to register the page's `onResourceRequested` callback using the `PhantomJSDriver#executePhantomJS` method.

Here is an example of disabling Google Analytic requests:

```
PhantomJSDriver driver = new PhantomJSDriver(service, capabilities);
driver.executePhantomJS("this.onResourceRequested = function(request, net) {" +
        "   console.log('REQUEST ' + request.url);" +
        "   if (request.url.indexOf('google-analytics') !== -1) {" +
        "       console.log('Abort ' + request.url);" +
        "       net.abort();" +
        "   }" +
        "};");
```